# Resolving maven dependencies

Tags: maven-2, maven, maven-plugin

Inovking maven2 goal `mvn dependency:list` on an artifact pom causes to download the whole dependent artifact packages. I think only those pom files are necessary for resolving dependencies. Aren't they?

Comment: I don't really understand your question. Do you ask if downloading pom.xml would suffice for resolving dependencies ?

Comment: yes, i needn't get the packages but display the list of dependencies.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

On the [dependecy plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/) documentation you can read that `dependency:list` is an alias for [`dependency:resolve`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/resolve-mojo.html). What you need is [`dependency:tree`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/tree-mojo.html) which :

> Displays the dependency tree for this project.

Even with `dependency:tree` you will have to download dependencies.

[From Arnaud Héritier](http://www.wakaleo.com/blog/246-maven-mythbusters-maven-automatically-updates-for-every-build#comment-57) (developer on Maven Project)

> This is a problem in maven core which doesn't allow in 2.x to resolve dependencies without downloading artifacts.

Comment: "tree" turned to download too.

Comment: It turns out that it's a maven 2 bug.

Comment: Are "dependency:resolve/list/tree" goals of too little use for such bug to surface?

Comment: I think they're working on it. Maybe for maven 3. But as said in the quote, it a problem in maven core, maybe not that easy to correct.

Comment: I got an exsiting maven2 project with huge maven dependencies. They're already installed locally, but certainly not in mvn local repos. After asking "maven, check what we need", i got everything doubled.

Comment: That's not a bug, that's by design (what is resolving a dependency if not downloading it?).

Comment: You can resolve dependencies by downloading the tree of dependencies pom, without downloading dependencies themselves. I don't need to download every spring dependency to know what they need, the pom.xml should suffice (and that's the OP question).

Comment: Ahhh, got the question now. But I wouldn't call that resolving, resolving means actually downloading an artifact for me.

Comment: Do you know if this has been solved on modern versions of maven? cc @ColinHebert

Answer (score 1):

Each mojo (plug-in in the Apache Maven) has a functionality description. See all [dependency plugin functionality](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/plugin-info.html).

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Answer (score 0):

I am working with the current edition of Maven (the plug-in that shipped with Eclipse Neon), and I'm still working to get my head around how to make it do all the magical things it is claimed to be able to do.

I have the screen pictured below, in which the dependency highlighted in the left pane is unresolved.
[!Dependency tree, showing missing dependency[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/65vrR.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/65vrR.png)

I thought that selecting (executing) the Update Project item off the project's context menu, as shown in the following image, would resolve it, but it left me with three errors, all, one way or another, the result of a missing dependency.

[!Maven fly-out menu in project context menu[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDIzq.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDIzq.png)

By examining the file system, I have confirmed that the dependency is, in fact, absent.

Color me confused; why didn't that action download the missing dependency?

Comment: Color me less confused, and using the Maven CLI in lieu of the plug-in for Eclipse.